# Simple testrunner setup for Groovy

Tags: testing, groovy, junit

I have a Jenkins shared library that has a bunch of classes in it, implemented in groovy, in the `src/company` folder. I have tests covering these and can run them locally by just invoking each file on its own, eg:

```
groovy --classpath src test/ThingTest.groovy
```

However, now I'm looking for something like Python's nose or pytest that I can run from CI and will discover/invoke each test, and afterward generate a nice XML summary. I found JUnit and Spock, but both seem to require immediately committing to hundreds of lines of pom/gradle/whatever files— this feels like a lot of potential maintenance burden to take on for someone otherwise outside the Java ecosystem who just wants to conveniently run some tests on every commit— especially when I don't even need that buildsystem stuff for the Jenkins shared library stuff, *just* for testing it!

As a novice who wants to do better at testing the reusable components of my Jenkins pipelines, where is the best and simplest place to start here? To be clear, I'm explicitly trying not to reinvent the wheel, but I don't want to have to install a special IDE just to be able to edit the boilerplate files needed for this— my hope is that a Java ecosystem expert can look at these requirements and say "cool, use X and Y, here's how to get a bare minimum setup to get that going".

The tests currently look like this, but there aren't that many of them, so it would be easy to change them to something else if that's required:

```java
import groovy.test.GroovyTestCase
import org.junit.Test

import myorg.jenkins.Thing


class ThingTest extends GroovyTestCase {
  @Test
  public void testThing() {
    // stuff followed by assertEquals
  }
```

---

Following the advice of @kriegaex I have a partly-working Gradle setup now that looks like this:

```java
plugins {
    id 'groovy'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.apache.groovy:groovy:4.0.14'
    implementation 'org.apache.groovy:groovy-json:4.0.14'

    testImplementation 'org.apache.groovy:groovy-test:4.0.14'
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        groovy {
            srcDirs = ['src', 'vars']
        }
    }
    test {
        groovy {
            srcDirs = ['test']
        }
    }
}
```

However, I'm hitting some dependency issues on execution:

```
$ gradle test

> Task :compileGroovy FAILED
startup failed:
/home/mikepurvis/jenkins-pipeline-helper/src/clearpath/jenkins/CPRCommonFunctions.groovy: 2: unable to resolve class hudson.model.Hudson
 @ line 2, column 1.
   import hudson.model.Hudson;
   ^

/home/mikepurvis/jenkins-pipeline-helper/vars/abortBuilds.groovy: 1: unable to resolve class hudson.model.Result
 @ line 1, column 1.
   import hudson.model.Result
   ^

/home/mikepurvis/jenkins-pipeline-helper/vars/abortBuilds.groovy: 2: unable to resolve class hudson.model.Run
 @ line 2, column 1.
   import hudson.model.Run
   ^

/home/mikepurvis/jenkins-pipeline-helper/vars/abortBuilds.groovy: 3: unable to resolve class jenkins.model.CauseOfInterruption.UserInterruption
 @ line 3, column 1.
   import jenkins.model.CauseOfInterruption.UserInterruption
   ^
...
```

It looks like there are a few tools out there that try to mock the jenkins/pipeline APIs for testing purposes, but I briefly tried one and it didn't seem to make it anywhere. I also wasn't successful in just directly pulling stuff from `com.cloudbees` into the build either. For example "Jenkins Core" is listed here with a specific pasteable Gradle snippet:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jenkins-ci.main/jenkins-core/2.439

However adding that to my build fails with a could-not-resolve:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileGroovy'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve org.jenkins-ci.main:jenkins-core:2.439.
```

Possibly it would be easier to tell Gradle not to bother trying to compile this as a project at all? That's unfortunate, though, given that it would be nice to have the additional validation of that even for the helper methods that don't yet have real tests.

Comment: You can just run your tests from Jenkins with a freestyle job. But if you know Nose and pytest, you probably know that they also come with features and scaffolding you need to learn how to use. Both Spock and JUnit are no rocket science to set up, and Spock is even fun to use. With Maven Surefire, you get your test reports, and Gradle has equivalent functionality. (I am biased towards Maven & Spock.) IMO, the real maintenance overhead is to reinvent the wheel and do things manually which there are established tools and community support for.

Comment: BTW, Surefire can also be set up to run your own [POJO tests](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/pojo-test.html), is that is what you prefer. But again, you need to set up a little Maven POM.

Comment: how your test looks like?

Comment: @kriegaex Absolutely, that's why I'm here to see if the community can help me select the best tools for the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for showing a sample test in your updated question. Actually, the test does not make any sense like that. The built-in `GroovyTestCase`  is a JUnit 3 class, but `@Test` is from JUnit 4 (and there is yet another `@Test` with another package name in JUnit 5 Jupiter). So, you can just omit the `@Test` annotations altogether and rely on class and method naming. So, given a file *src/test/groovy/ThingTest.groovy* like this:

```java
import groovy.test.GroovyTestCase

class ThingTest extends GroovyTestCase {
  void testPassing() {
    assert true
  }

  void testFailing() {
    assert false
  }
}
```

you can build and run it in Gradle like this:

```java
plugins {
  id 'groovy'
}

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'org.apache.groovy:groovy:4.0.14'
  testImplementation 'org.apache.groovy:groovy-test:4.0.14'
}
```

Then just run `gradle test`.

To build and run the same in Maven with `mvn test`, use this POM (a bit more wordy, because Maven is not so "groovy" out of the box):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>dev.aspectj</groupId>
  <artifactId>Maven_POJOTestsGroovy</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <groovy.version>4.0.14</groovy.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.groovy</groupId>
      <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
      <version>${groovy.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.groovy</groupId>
      <artifactId>groovy-test</artifactId>
      <version>${groovy.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
        <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.13.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>execute</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
            <version>${groovy.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Besides, this little [POJO test](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/pojo-test.html) in Java...

```java
public class ThingTest {
  public void testPassing() {
    assert true;
  }

  public void testFailing() {
    assert false;
  }
}
```

... would need a smaller POM:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>dev.aspectj</groupId>
  <artifactId>Maven_POJOTests</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

</project>
```

While the Groovy test indirectly depends on JUnit 3, this POJO test does not even need that.

You see, you have many options without much setup effort. For Spock, it would not be much more both in Gradle and Maven. But if you are happy with your JUnit-3-style `GroovyTest`, maybe that really is all you need, even though you are losing a lot of testing comfort when not using Spock (ideally) or JUnit 5 (second choice).

Comment: Wow, this is awesome— very comprehensive. I tried going the Gradle/JUnit/groovy-test route for now and started hitting issues with further dependencies. Since Gradle is now trying to "compile" the whole repo as a project, it's getting caught up on non-pure helper functions that do stuff like `import hudson.model`, and I've tried a few options for how to get Gradle to supply those (incl something called jenkins-pipeline-unit). I'll update the question body with the current status.

Comment: Oh, so sorry. I'm not a seasoned SO user and more used to the forum model. Accepting now.

Comment: Thank you. BTW, did you see the [Jenkins testing guide](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/developer/testing/)? It took me 10 seconds to find with my favourite search engine. Maybe that helps you to set up proper testing. I have never developed a Jenkins plugin, but that is where I would start looking first, if I were you.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of it, but unfortunately it's for plugins not shared libraries. The corresponding shared library doc has nothing to say about build or testing: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/

Comment: Sorry, as a mere Jenkins user (not developer) I was unaware of the difference between plugins and shared libraries. I guess, you probably know [this article](https://medium.com/disney-streaming/testing-jenkins-shared-libraries-4d4939406fa2) and the [JenkinsPipelineUnit](https://github.com/jenkinsci/JenkinsPipelineUnit) framework. You mentioned (without naming sources), that you tried existing tools but got nowhere, which is not a debuggable problem description.  I have not seen you post a new, more specific question yet.

Comment: I'll think about it further and see if it's worth the bother. Ironically, the Jenkins ecosystem seems to have very little culture around testing the pipelines themselves or pipeline components, so it feels like some of this is swimming upriver.

Comment: Well, is it worth the bother that your home-brew solution is still not doing what it is supposed to? BTW, sorry I cannot change the Jenkins ecosystem for you. I just meant to help a bit, initially finding your question, because it was falsely tagged with _spock_, because obviously Spock is exactly what you do **not** want to use. That is the reason why Spock maintainer Leonard Brünings has removed the tag in his edit.

Comment: I originally tagged with Spock because of the jenkins-spock project, but that looks to maybe now be abandonware.

Comment: I did get a `gradle test` solution basically working, I just have to exclude anything from the SourceSet that imports a Jenkins object. That's already an improvement over what was before.

Comment: This was the jenkins-spock tutorial I was trying to follow, but the upfront commitment to a 200-line pom.xml kind of scared me off: https://itnext.io/unit-testing-a-jenkins-shared-library-9bfb6b599748